# Single or divorced, how long ago

Tags: injury

Work related injury, their doctor wants to know if I am single or divorced, how long ago was I divorced, how many children, how old are they, every surgery of my life.  I hurt my shoulder. Marital status is a moot point. A surgery 40 years ago has zero impact. They are fishing?

Comment: I get asked this every time I get a new doctor, including family history all the way to my grandparents. What do you believe they would be fishing for?

Comment: @RonBeyer Weird doctors you have, I've never been asked anything about my relationship status or family - unless there was a clear reason, like whether a certain illness has a history in my family. It would generally appear quite invading and inappropriate if any new doctor would ask around like that. It may be a bit more common in rural areas where there is a good chance the doc knows your folks and asks out of curiosity about parents - small talk like that seems to be more common in such areas in general. The question of previous illnesses etc. seems more or less normal though.

Comment: Could you tell us roughly where you are? Which Country / region and whether it's on the countryside or a big city? The cultural context can make a difference in judging what's considered normal and what not.

Comment: "They are fishing?" is not a question - what is your question?

Comment: @DaleM I think it is fair to assume that the true question is whether a non-treating physician is allowed to ask those questions in connection with evaluating a worker's compensation claim.

Comment: @RonBeyer The problem with that theory is the single v. divorced status, date of divorce, number of children and their ages all have nothing to do with determining your medical history. Medical history asks about ancestors, uncles, aunts, cousins, etc. and is specific to whether any of those people (if you have them) suffered particular health problems, not whether you have any or not.

Comment: Kids can imply fatigue, not enough sleep, stress, exposure to illness. Marriage/partnership/divorce--whether there's someone who can help take care of you or may be a source of stress. Invasive, yes, but may still have medical implications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about the law or legal process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about law.

Answer (score 2):

> Work related injury, **their doctor** wants to know if I am single or
>   divorced, how long ago was I divorced, how many children, how old are
>   they, every surgery of my life. I hurt my shoulder. Marital status is
>   a moot point. A surgery 40 years ago has zero impact. They are
>   fishing?

All prior surgery is a pretty ordinary request and is relevant. It makes it possible to better determine the cause of injury and no surgery within 40 years is more good than bad to you.

Whether you are single or divorced, how many children you have and how old they are is only relevant if you are dead, because in that situation, it determines who has a right to bring a wrongful death action or receive worker's compensation benefits in connection with your death. Since you are not dead, and this is not your treating physician (who might want to have emergency contact information, or to explore family health history), it is hard to see how this would be relevant.

He may be attempting to explore if there is another potential source of payment for the injuries which is not appropriate to ask, or for witnesses who can be interviewed to confirm or dispute your injuries.

The only exception which could be relevant, which would make number of children and their ages relevant, would be if the injury would impact something that is also impacted by childbirth (e.g. a C-section).

When you got divorced, if you got divorced, is pretty much never relevant.

Comment: A [comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/single-or-divorced-how-long-ago#comment79178_42474 "Kids can imply fatigue, not enough sleep, stress, exposure to illness. Marriage/partnership/divorce--whether there's someone who can help take care of you or may be a source of stress. ...") by mkennedy raises an interesting point: family circumstances could provide context.  Could the existence for example of child care duties have an impact on evaluating the veracity of the claim for the injured shoulder, or the impact of the injury on the injured worker?

Comment: @phoog Evaluating the veracity of the claim is pretty problematic (all workplace injuries even if only partially due to work are covered), and normally, only the impact on the injured worker at work is legally relevant. So, I doubtful that this is entitled to the benefit of the doubt (and even then . . . when you got divorced if you did get divorced wouldn't be proper).